# how to pass function agruments(pointer, reference) to a "new thread" and expect return value?

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, return, pthreads

I'm trying pass the pointer received from a member function of a class to another member function of that same class using thread and expect a return value.

```
    class tictactoe
    {
    ...
    ..
    .
    };
    
    class AI {
    public:
        int pickSpot(tictactoe* game){
             t =  new thread([this]() {findOptions(game);} );
             return 0;
        }
        
        int findOptions(tictactoe* game){ return 0;}
    };
```

results in error:
error: variable 'game' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

how it's done?

Comment: `[this]` -> `[this, game]`

Comment: thnx, one problem down.

Comment: or : t =  new thread([this]( auto game_arg ) { findOptions( game_arg ); } ,game );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the return value you can us std::future and std::async:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int pickSpot(tictactoe* game){
    std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this, game]() { return findOptions(game); });
    f.wait();
    int res = f.get();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thnx alot, but ...
error: no viable conversion from 'future<__async_result_of<(lambda at /TICTACTOE/main.cpp:268:61)>>' to 'future<int>'

Comment: /usr/include/c++/9/future:779: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'future<__async_result_of<(lambda at /TICTACTOE/main.cpp:268:61)> >' (aka 'future<void>') to 'std::future<int> &&' for 1st argument